# Gyroscope value in titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, gyroscope

Is there any way to get the gyroscope data in titanium? Just like there is an API given to access the [accelerometer](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Accelerometer) data.

Answer (score 1):

Not presently, but there is a relatively easy way for you to add some code to an existing module that already uses CoreMotion.

Ben Bahrenburg's module, available here: https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Ti.CoreMotion/ uses CoreMotion to expose a step counter. So it already has the framework referenced, and the module set up, building, etc. That's the tough stuff. So just pull it down, make sure you can `./build.py` it yourself, then expose the gyroscope. Send a PR to him when you're done, and give back to the community!

```
static const NSTimeInterval gyroMin = 0.01;

- (id)startGyro:(id)args {

     // Determine the update interval
     NSTimeInterval delta = 0.005;
     NSTimeInterval updateInterval = gyroMin + delta;

     // Create a CMMotionManager
     CMMotionManager *mManager = [(APLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] sharedManager];
     APLGyroGraphViewController * __weak weakSelf = self;

     // Check whether the gyroscope is available
     if ([mManager isGyroAvailable] == YES) {
          // Assign the update interval to the motion manager
          [mManager setGyroUpdateInterval:updateInterval];
          [mManager startGyroUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMGyroData *gyroData, NSError *error) {
               // TODO: Do something with gyroData.rotationRate.x, y, and z.
          }];
     }
     return nil;
}

- (id)stopUpdates:(id)args {
     CMMotionManager *mManager = [(APLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] sharedManager];
     if ([mManager isGyroActive] == YES) {
          [mManager stopGyroUpdates];
     }
     return nil;
}
```

Remember: With Core Motion, you have to test and debug your app on a device. There is no support in iOS Simulator for accelerometer or gyroscope data.

Code adapted from:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html